# Remove last and from a python string if it's there

Tags: python

I'm getting string data into my python code.Some time data is coming with an extra "and" or " or  for example

```
Tom and Mark and
```

in this case I need to remove the last "and" & final outcome will look like

```
Tom and Mark
```

But when data will come like this

```
Harry and John
```

Then I will consider the data without removing the "and"

Can you suggest me how to do that?

Comment: You test the string to see whether it ends with "and"; if so, remove it?  Each of those is a basic, well-documented operation in Python tutorials and textbooks.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: When there's an "and" at the end, is there always a space following that as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex

```
import re
s = re.sub('\s+and\s*$', '', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `str.strip()` function and string *slicing*:

```
lst = ['Tom and Mark and ', 'Harry and John', 'Bland and']

for s in lst:
    s = s.strip()
    s = s[:-4] if s[-4:] == ' and' else s
    print(s)
```

The output:

```
Tom and Mark
Harry and John
Bland
```

Comment: `rstrip()` doesn't work like that. Try your solution with something like 'Bland and'.